# What are models of inconsistent theory?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, model-theory

Consider arbitrary language $\mathcal{L}$, inconsistent theory $T$ (e.g. $T=\{ \forall x P(x) \land \forall x \neg P(x) \}$ for $\mathcal{L}=\{P\}$) and $A = \{\ \mathcal{M} \mid \mathcal{M} \models T \}$. How does the set $A$ look like?

Comment: $A=\varnothing$

Comment: An inconsistent theory gas no models.

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti Can you please post it as answer so I can accept it?

Comment: If you allow empty models, then your $T$ is not inconsistent.

Comment: We can fix @EricWofsey's point by changing one of the $\forall$s to $\exists$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An inconsistent theory has no models, so $A=\varnothing$.